# Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com' on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu

I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution to my problem. Everything I've tried hasn't worked so far.

From what I understand, this is an internet connection problem or a DNS issue. I followed [this tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#3-wifi-or-ethernet) to setup Ubuntu Server on my new Raspberry Pi 4. I'm using wifi and Ethernet just to be sure.

Some have suggested to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in /etc/resolv.conf. Not only it doesn't work, but every time I `sudo reboot`, the file content turn back to initial.

I even tried `sudo ufw allow out 53,113,123/udp`. No positive result.

Does anyone have an other idea that can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Ubuntu Server uses Netplan (and cloudinit) to manage network settings, you shouldn't tamper with the config files manually.

Comment: @tttapa This issue persists even without tampering with network config files. I'm connected via ethernet and I still have this issue. It seems like Ubuntu doesn't setup ethernet correctly in the default case? Another Pi on the same switch (different OS) can connect fine.

Comment: I should also add that the same hardware was able to access the Internet just fine with a different image (same SD card, same Pi, same cables, same switch, etc). Also, strangely while the Internet doesn't seem to work, I can ssh in from LAN.